# how to install Ubuntu on Lenovo g50-70

Tags: dual-boot

I need help in installing ubuntu on my lenovo G50-70 pc.
I looking for a dual OS setup on my laptop .
Currently I have windows 8.1 intstalled on my pc, Suggest me what is the best veison of Ubuntu that I can install on this pc.
This is my pc's configuration

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise
Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name KUTTU
System Manufacturer LENOVO
System Model    20351
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  LENOVO_MT_20351_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo G50-70
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 1900 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   LENOVO 9ACN32WW, 7/20/2015
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 0.32
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  LENOVO
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.3.9600.17196"
User Name   Kuttu\KUTTU\Arjun
Time Zone   India Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   3.90 GB
Available Physical Memory   0.98 GB
Total Virtual Memory    7.90 GB
Available Virtual Memory    3.63 GB
Page File Space 4.00 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes


Display 


Name    Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_380C17AA&REV_0B\3&11583659&0&10
Adapter Type    Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Intel Corporation compatible
Adapter Description Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Adapter RAM 1.00 GB (1,073,741,824 bytes)
Installed Drivers   igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32
Driver Version  10.18.14.4264
INF File    oem75.inf (iHSWM_w81 section)
Color Planes    Not Available
Color Table Entries 4294967296
Resolution  1366 x 768 x 60 hertz
Bits/Pixel  32
Memory Address  0xD0000000-0xD03FFFFF
Memory Address  0xC0000000-0xCFFFFFFF
I/O Port    0x00006000-0x0000603F
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967289
I/O Port    0x000003B0-0x000003BB
I/O Port    0x000003C0-0x000003DF
Memory Address  0xA0000-0xBFFFF
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\igdkmd64.sys (10.18.14.4264, 4.70 MB (4,928,256 bytes), 8/9/2015 4:50 AM)

Name    AMD Radeon R5 M230
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_666F&SUBSYS_380C17AA&REV_00\4&3420519A&0&00E4
Adapter Type    AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x666F), Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. compatible
Adapter Description AMD Radeon R5 M230
Adapter RAM (2,147,483,648) bytes
Installed Drivers   aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
Driver Version  13.250.31.0
INF File    oem20.inf (ati2mtag_R503 section)
Color Planes    Not Available
Color Table Entries Not Available
Resolution  Not Available
Bits/Pixel  Not Available
Memory Address  0xB0000000-0xBFFFFFFF
Memory Address  0xD0400000-0xD04FFFFF
I/O Port    0x00003F00-0x00003FFF
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967290
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\atikmpag.sys (8.14.1.6354, 609.50 KB (624,128 bytes), 1/28/2014 12:22 PM)
```

Help me how much of harddrive space is on the pc for the installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score -1):

You can install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with your Windows 8.1.

1. Back up Windows
2. Create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive
3. Install Ubuntu
4. Boot Repair
5. Fix the boot loader
6. Reboot into Ubuntu
7. Reboot into Windows

Please refer to this documentaion

[Inatall Ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8.1](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.